# Multiple Powershell command needs to be run from command line

Tags: powershell, cmd, timespan

i need to run single line powershell script like this one:

```
$a = Get-Content test.tmp; $b = [timespan]::fromseconds($a); "{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}" -f ([datetime]$b.Ticks)
```

in command line. When running it directly from powerhsell cli it work fine. but when trying run:

```
powershell "$a = Get-Content test.tmp; $b = [timespan]::fromseconds($a); "{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}" -f ([datetime]$b.Ticks)"
```

from command line cli i get error. I cannot run it from script in form of .ps1 file as i am not allowed to change restriction policy regarding to run powershell script.

Anybodoy would be able to point me what i have to change to run it properly from command line?

Many thanks

Comment: `powershell -Command "$a = Get-Content test.tmp; $b = [timespan]::fromseconds($a); \"{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}\" -f ([datetime]$b.Ticks)"`

Answer (score 0):

With proper quoting / parentheses you need no intermediate variables and only one command:

```
'{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}' -f ([datetime]([timespan]::fromseconds((Get-Content test.tmp))).Ticks)
```

In a batch:

```
powershell -C "'{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}' -f ([datetime]([timespan]::fromseconds((Get-Content test.tmp))).Ticks)"
```

Or to get the duration into a batch variable:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\23\SO_46379453.cmd
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (
    'powershell -C "\"{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}\" -f ([datetime]([timespan]::fromseconds((Get-Content test.tmp))).Ticks)" '
) Do Set "Duration=%%A,%%B"
set Duration
```